# Running command found in PATH?

Tags: path, environment-variables, qt5, qprocess

I'm trying to run a command via `QProcess` but it's not working. My command is something like `utility -someflag /path/to/file`. `utility` is in the PATH, however it seems `QProcess` is not using this environment variable.

The command simply fails and I need to specify the full path of the utility (which I'd like to avoid).

Is there any way around this? Basically some way to make `QProcess` use the PATH variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that it depends on how the application is started. This is on OSX but it might be similar in other platforms:

- If it's a command line application and started from a terminal then it will have access to the env variables.
- If it's started from Qt Creator, it will not have access to any env variable.
- If it's a GUI application (.app), it will not have access to the env variables.

The solution in my case, since it is a GUI application, was to update the .app package manually. First the file **Info.plist** needs to be changed from this:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>MyApplication</string>
```

to this:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>MyApplication.sh</string>
```

Then, still in the app package, in **Contents/MacOS**, create a new file with the same name as the application, but with a .sh extension, eg. "MyApplication.sh". Then create the launcher:

```
#!/bin/sh
SCRIPT_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
source ~/.bash_profile
logger "$SCRIPT_DIR/MyApplication"
exec "$SCRIPT_DIR/MyApplication" $@
```

The `source ~/.bash_profile` line in particular ensures that all the environment (including PATH variable) will be set properly.